# Removing special characters from filename

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, special-characters

I'm making a website where people can upload images. However when end-users are uploading an image that contains special characters or a foreign character, the image does upload, But It cannot be display'd on the website, Like the image doesn't exist on the server.

I see a lot of people answering on another post saying that I need to use `preg_replace`

But the thing is, I don't really know how to use it. How would I use it in my code.

Here is my controller method:

```
public function upload(Requests\CreatePostsRequest $request)
{
        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $findme   = ".";
        $pos = strpos($target_file, $findme);
        //echo $target_file;
        //dd($_POST);
        echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"];
        $imageFileType = strtolower(substr($target_file,$pos+1));
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                //$check = true;
                //dd($check);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
        $filecheck = 0;
        $orgFileName = $target_file;
        while (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $target_file = substr($orgFileName,0,$pos).$filecheck.substr($orgFileName,$pos);
            $filecheck++;

            $uploadOk = 1;
        }

        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000*8) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                echo $imageFileType;
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

                        $post = new Posts($request->all());
                        $post->fileToUpload = $target_file;
                        Auth::user()->posts()->save($post);
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
        return redirect('');
        echo $target_file;
    }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using preg replace:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_\-\.]/i", '', basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"]));
```

This will remove all characters that's not a letter (a-z), a number (0-9) or a dash, underscore or dot (we want to keep the file extension). The `i` flag in the end makes the match case insensitive.

#### Update

To make the expression shorter, you can replace `a-z0-9\_`-part with the word token `\w`.
The pattern would then be: `/[^\w\-\.]/`. Here we don't need the `i` flag, since the word token handles that for us.

Comment: This doesn't work, It won't remove the "+" in the filename. Am I doing it right?

`$target_dir = "uploads/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']["name"]);
   $target_file = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\_\-]/", '', $target_file);`

Comment: @EiðurGeirVilhelmsson - Awesome. Yes, I was a bit quick with the save button. Had do change it a couple of times..  Lycka till :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You Rock!

Comment: For the down voters. If you feel this answer is of such poor quality that you want to down vote it, please add a comment explaining why. It's hard to fix the answer if you don't know what the problem with it is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Your solution works perfectly for me!